# iQuery submit form without page reload

Tags: jquery

I have a form which has one hidden field and one button. When the button is clicked I want it to run a jquery script which in turn calls a PHP script to update the underlying data table.

How do I make the jQuery function run when the form button is clicked.

My jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#roominput').click(function(){
        $.post('alert_update.php', { recordid: form1.RecordID.value },
        function(result) {
            console.log();
        });
    });
});
```

My form

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" id="ajax">
    <input type="image" src="../../../../conf_images/butler_request.png" name="alert_button" id="alert_button" value="Submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1" />
    <input type="hidden" id="alert" name="RecordID" value="<?php echo $row_ConfAlert['RecordID']; ?>" />
</form>
```

Can anyone help me with this issue, many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `submit` event of form instead of click. Then use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent reload. Then use `$(this).serialize()` to get form data and pass to server.

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('alert_update.php', $(this).serialize(), function(result) {
         console.log();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you also can use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#roominput').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: "alert_update.php",
          dataType: 'json', //if your data type is json
          data: $('#form1 [name="RecordID"]').val(),
          success: function(response) {
            console.log();
          }
        });
        return false;
    });
    $('#form1').on("submit", function(){
      return false;
    })
});   
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Shayanyp and Rejith, I have tried both methods but the data table is not getting updated, there is also nothing in the console log. Any ideas why?

Comment: @DCJones wooow , do you need this submit form data-table? what's the code of your data-table? what's the response of your ajax ("alert_update.php") ?, need more details to solve your problem. by the way, check if the ajax request fire or not